# Check values of HashMap <Object,String>

Tags: java, hashmap, java-collections-api

I have an IntPair class which has two methods I use from it: "getFirst()" and "getSecond()". While in this method I'm currently working, I want to check if "hashMap j" contains a specific value and then do the actions. I think I have the problem in these lines:

```
Object obj = j.values();
t.moveCursor(((IntPair)obj).getFirst(), ((IntPair)obj).getSecond());
```

I don't know if I'm casting ok to the Object, or if the first line "Object obj = j.values()" should be replaced with another method call.
I tested with a System.out.print ("Message") after j.containsValue("0") and I got the message back.

This is a part of the method I'm trying to make it work.

```
public static HashMap<IntPair, String> j = new HashMap<>();

j.put(new IntPair(firstInt, secondInt), value);
if (j.containsValue("0"))
{
Object obj = j.values();
t.moveCursor(((IntPair)obj).getFirst(), ((IntPair)obj).getSecond());
t.putCharacter('x');
}
else if (j.containsValue("1"))
{
Object obj = j.values();
t.moveCursor(((IntPair)obj).getFirst(), ((IntPair)obj).getSecond());
t.putCharacter('v');
}
```

IntPair Class:

```
public class IntPair {
private final int first;
private final int second;

public IntPair(int first, int second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 89 * hash + this.first;
    hash = 89 * hash + this.second;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final IntPair other = (IntPair) obj;
    if (this.first != other.first) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.second != other.second) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public int getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public int getSecond() {
    return second;
}
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: 1) I don't see a complete method where you state, `"this is the method..."`. 2) I assume (and certainly hope) that your IntPair class overrides equals and hashCode() appropriately, correct? 3) I am not sure what exactly it is you're asking or that you're stuck on. You mention a question about casting -- is your attempt to cast causing an error or exception?

Answer (score 1):

There is a big issue with the code you have written
 In line

```
t.moveCursor(((IntPair)obj).getFirst(), ((IntPair)obj).getSecond());
```

the expression

```
((IntPair)obj).getFirst()
```

wont return the getFirst value as obj here is not of type IntPair but obj is a collection of elements IntPair returned by

```
Object obj = j.values();
```

so you have to retrieve IntPair element from this collection and then you can read getFirst()
I have written a small program to make my point

```
public static HashMap<IntPair, String> j = new HashMap<IntPair, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        j.put(new IntPair(2, 3), "0");
        if (j.containsValue("0")) {
            Set<Entry<IntPair, String>> pairs = j.entrySet();
            Iterator<Entry<IntPair, String>> it = pairs.iterator();
            Entry e;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                e = it.next();
                if (e.getValue().equals("0")) {
                    IntPair resultObj = (IntPair) e.getKey();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `values()` method returns a Collection of the values objects, here a Collection of Strings. You can't cast this to IntPair, and I'm surprised that your attempt is not causing a compiler error.

Comment: I edited the question.
What should I use instead of values() ?

Comment: @XhensB: what are you trying to achieve? What error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: I'm not getting any error but the code is not working for me.
I have a terminal screen and I want to take values from hashMap and than pass them as arguments at the method moveCursor(int x, int y).
After I move the cursor to desired location, I want to fill it with characters. And the result is that I have a blank screen in the end.